# Error while copying war file from workstation to client node?`

Tags: copy, chef-infra, war, chef-recipe

Hi I am using chef for deployment, I have created a war file on my chef workstation and copied it to my templates folder of cookbook
[image: chef-workstation]
now I have written a simple recipe to copy it to my client here is the recipe

```
template "/opt/tomcat7/webapps/SampleProject.war" do
  source "SampleProject.war"
end
```

Now if I run the recipe from my chef-workstation using knife ssh it is unable to copy the war file

```
 knife ssh 'name:staging2.akosha.com' 'chef-client' -x root -P
```

[image: knife ssh]

but if I give some other file like *.txt it copies the file successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a reference for that anywhere, but you shouldn't use the `template` resource for binaries - the same happened to me also. It seems that the erb-processing flips some bits.

Instead, use the `cookbook_file` resource, or better the `remote_file`, to avoid polluting your Chef server with large artifacts (which do not really belong there).

Comment: trick worked with cookbook_file , I was unaware of issues with the binary file. thanks :)